# SSH to a remote host via JumpHost

Tags: putty

I want to ssh to a remote host via the jump host. but I want to use supperputty.is there a way to achieve this requirement using plink/proxycmd ...etc.

Can somebody help me on "Extra Putty Arguments" in superputty?

Thank you
Luke

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).